# Bot Channels Registration: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AppRegPortal.Providers.Graph.GraphException'

Tags: botframework

After create bot channel on Azure Bot Channels Registration and try add Microsoft Graph rules on apps.dev.microsoft.com I have an exception:

Bot Channels Registration: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AppRegPortal.Providers.Graph.GraphException' was thrown. After try to add Microsoft Graph rules and try save changes.

If I migrate Bot Channel from Microsoft Bot Framework
(https://dev.botframework.com/) to Azure - rules transferred successfully.

Comment: This underlying issue has been identified and is being addressed by the team. We apologize for the inconvenience

Answer (score 10):

Facing the same problem.

There is mention of it here but no help to me
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2887306/-connect-msolservice-exception-of-type-was-thrown-error-when-you-use-t

**However ... Found an alternate way to make this work**

1. Within Azure, select "Resources groups"->the name of your Bot
   Service.
2. Under the Settings section, select "Deployments" and then
   select deployment name of your Bot Service. The APPID and APPSECRET
   are view-able under the Inputs section.

Comment: Thanks for new way!
It's help for future, but now I have problem with Graph Rules. =(