# Microsoft Application Registration Portal not able to add Delegated and Application Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, azureportal

I am working on Microsoft Azure Bot Framework and using Application Registration portal to add the Delegated and Application Permissions(such as calendars.Read, Emails.Read) to my Bot Application. The permissions are not being added and giving the below Exception:

[image]

Comment: Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850752/bot-channels-registration-exception-of-type-microsoft-appregportal-providers-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on a fix for this problem. It should be out soon. I will ping you here when it's in production.

Regards,
Francisco

Comment: Hey Francisco, when is it supposed to be fixed. Any estimate ?

Comment: I have the same error when trying to add the web platform with the redicret URL to configure the connected services. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cortana/skills/configure-connected-account. Is this the same problem?